# Python BS4 with SDMX

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup, sdmx

I would like to retrieve data given in a SDMX file (like https://www.bundesbank.de/cae/servlet/StatisticDownload?tsId=BBK01.ST0304&its_fileFormat=sdmx&mode=its). I tried to use BeautifulSoup, but it seems, it does not see the tags. In the following the code

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
url = "https://www.bundesbank.de/cae/servlet/StatisticDownload?tsId=BBK01.ST0304&its_fileFormat=sdmx"
html_source = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'lxml')
ts_series = soup.findAll("bbk:Series")
```

which gives me an empty object.

Is BS4 the wrong tool, or (more likely) what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The supplied url says 'Your request could not be processed!', maybe just paste some xml snippet would help.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CompactData>
<bbk:DataSet datasetID="BBK01">
    <bbk:Series FREQ="D" BBK_ID="BBK01.ST0304">
      <bbk:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2016-08-24" OBS_VALUE="-0.339" BBK_DIFF="0.3"/>
      <bbk:Obs TIME_PERIOD="1999-01-04" OBS_VALUE="3.2"/>
      <bbk:Obs TIME_PERIOD="1999-01-03" BBK_OBS_STATUS="K"/>
    </bbk:Series>
  </bbk:DataSet>
</CompactData>

don't know how to format it correctly here. sorry

Comment: You're right, but the url is readable in python, at least on my system

Comment: There are specific libraries for the SDMX xml format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`soup.findAll("bbk:series")` would return the result.

In fact, in this case, even you use `lxml` as the parser, BeautifulSoup still parse it as html, since html tags are case insensetive, BeautifulSoup downcases all the tags, thus `soup.findAll("bbk:series")` works. See [Other parser problems](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems) from the official doc.

If you want to parse it as `xml`, use `soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'xml')` instead. It also uses `lxml` since `lxml` is the only `xml` parser BeautifulSoup has. Now you can use `ts_series = soup.findAll("Series")` to get the result as beautifulSoup will strip the namespace part `bbk`.

Comment: Oh dayum. Thank you so much. You saved my day after 2 hours useless testing :)